# Developer story has no link to my Stack Overflow profile anywhere

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, developer-story

I'm placing a link on my personal homepage to my StackOverflow profile. However, I do not want to link both my profile and my developer story. Since my site is like a short resume I would prefer to link the developer story.

But there is one thing that confuses me, the developer story does in no way link my StackOverflow (and any other StackExchange network site) profile.

[image: link the profiles]

Is this a desired behaviour? Or is this a setting I've not found yet? Is it possible to enable linking the profiles from within the story? If not, I would like to request that feature. It really makes sense at some point.

Comment: You can link to your top posts though. From there it is just a single click away to your profile.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's in the backlog, we just haven't got to it yet. It should be soon though!

**UPDATE**: I know it took a long time, but this one slipped away from us. I fixed it yesterday, your accounts are now linked from your story.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. \o/

Comment: Is there any concrete timeframe for this?

Comment: Two and half years later and looks like no link has been added...

Comment: @cassiomolin thanks for the ping, links deployed yesterday

Comment: @DeanWard Thanks for looking into that. I confirm it's working :)